# Getting the error "Class not registered. Looking for object with CLSID" in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I am getting error "Class not registered. Looking for object with CLSID."

[image]

I don't know why it is coming. I searched a lot but didn't get the solution. It was working fine but don't know why it is coming today. I am able to log in on my SQL Server but have not been able to run a query.

When I click on new query option, this issue is coming. Lot of my work is on hold due to this issue. Can anyone help me out what is the issue and how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling SSMS, and install SSMS again?

Comment: I did this it was resolved but came again after 4 to 5 months. I don't know why it is coming and how to resolve.

Comment: Perhaps something to do with a Windows update (either for SQL Server, the .NET framework, or something else still). Perhaps either was updated and not the other?